# How to create an overview over header files in c?

Tags: c, uml

I have a background in object oriented programming(Java).

To create an overview or to design classes, I usually create a Class Diagram.

I'm currently working on a project which is written in plain c.

I know that there is no classes in c but rather something more primitive call struct.

How can i create an overview over header files and c files. does any standard exist?

**UPDATE**:

I use visual studio as IDE.

Comment: Do you use IDE? Typical IDEs like VS and eclipse CDT offer features that generates call graph.

Comment: In the unix world, doxygen is a nice program that produces documentation from your sources, including different sorts of graphs: include hierarchie, call graph and also (IIRC) "used-by" graph. No idea if that works for your platform, though.

Answer (score 2):

In C you cannot create a class diagram because as you mentioned there are no classes. C has struct but C struct are data aggregate and not ADT. The only UML concept I may want to use for a C project is sequence diagram. A list of APIs and the call graph (as suggested by Iulyon) may be enough.